# Remove charsequence from String

Tags: string

Got charsequence contains from WUB

```
String pattern = "WUB";

String song = WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB
```

if apply method:

```
song = song.replaceAll(pattern, "");
```

Get a `String`

WEARETHECHAMPIONSMYFRIEND

How to get this `String` with spaces?

WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
song = song.replaceAll(pattern, " ").trim();
```

Just replace it with a whitespace and call trim on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Replace all instances of `pattern` in `song` with a space (`" "`) instead of an empty string (`""`).

```
song = song.replaceAll(pattern, " ");
```